# How do I trigger a website clock from AM to PM correctly?

Tags: javascript

I have a different but slightly related to one I asked yesterday. This clock is now working fine and I have the time and suffix styled differently using CSS. However, the problem with the below code is that the suffix doesn't change to PM until the time is 1pm rather than the 12pm it should be. I'm have little idea about using javascript so any help would be appreciated as to how to fix the problem. The code I'm using is below.

```
function renderTime() {
var currentTime = new Date();
var diem = "AM";
var h = currentTime.getHours();
var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
var s = currentTime.getSeconds();
setTimeout('renderTime()',1000);
if (h == 0) {
    h = 12;
} else if (h > 12) { 
    h = h - 12;
    diem="PM";
}

if (m < 10) {
    m = "0" + m;
}
if (s < 10) {
    s = "0" + s;
}
document.getElementById("clockDisplay-time").innerText = h + ":" + m;
document.getElementById("clockDisplay-suffix").innerText = diem;
}
renderTime();
```

Comment: @putvande—then the OP will get h == 0. If the test is changed as you suggest, the next line needs to be something like: `h = (h - 12) || 12;` to avoid getting `00:00pm`.

Comment: That worked great thanks RobG, using your and putvande's suggestions together. So far things seem great, I'll keep my eye on it and see if it's still behaving come tomorrow morning. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (h > 12)
```

should be

```
else if (h >= 12)
```

so that for h=12 it will be PM.